# How to export or backup Sphinx indexes

Tags: backup, search-engine, sphinx

I have a Sphinx install on a server. I would like to copy the data created by sphinx during indexations (basically for backup or to provide exact copy for dev team).

Do I have another solution than copying files from {your_install}/data/*.sp* ?

(In this case, .spl files are protected, but they are empty, are they usefull or there are only lock files ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the .spl is only a lockfile - no there is no need to back it up.

I think the only option is to backup the data files as you note.

Note if you have RT indexes, then there might be other extensions (I think .ram). You should also backup the Binlog. 
Although do see ['FLUSH RTINDEX'](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-flush-rtindex) - that makes for cleaner backups.

Comment: If you're backing up RT indexes, there's an official blog post on how to do that at http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2011/11/18/backing-up-rt-indexes/